# React Form returning null values with useRef() hook

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to get input data from the user when they click submit form button. When clicked, i'm getting a response object with null values shown in the screenshot. From what I understand, I don't want useState because it'll make the page do a re-render, and I don't want that. This is my first time with useRef, is there something i'm missing?

```js
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { useRef } from "react";

const ContactSection = () => {
  let nameRef = useRef(null); // name
  let emailRef = useRef(null); // email
  let messageRef = useRef(null); // message

  const formSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      name: nameRef.current.value,
      email: emailRef.current.value,
      message: messageRef.current.value,
    };
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <Box component="form">
            <TextField
              ref={nameRef}
              type="text"
              id="form-name"
              label="Name"
              sx={{ mt: 2 }}
            ></TextField>
            <TextField
              ref={emailRef}
              type="email"
              id="form-email"
              label="Email"
              sx={{ mt: 2 }}
            ></TextField>
            <TextField
              ref={messageRef}
              type="text"
              id="form-msg"
              label="Message"
              multiline
              rows={5}
              sx={{ mt: 2 }}
            ></TextField>
   </Box>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={formSubmit}
            sx={{
              mt: 4,
              "&:hover": {
                color: "secondary.main",
                transition: "ease-in 0.2s",
                transform: "scale(1.05)",
              },
            }}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
  );
};
export default ContactSection;
```

I'm getting this error in the console when trigger formSubmit handle

[image: Console Error]

Comment: why useRef... ref are used to maintain the same state for all the lifecycle of a component.. for a form you need to use `useState`  . create a object with state and use onChange method on text fields to update state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using MUI TextField change the ref to inputRef

```
    <Box component="form">
    <TextField
      inputRef={nameRef}
      type="text"
      id="form-name"
      label="Name"
      sx={{ mt: 2 }}
    ></TextField>
    <TextField
      inputRef={emailRef}
      type="email"
      id="form-email"
      label="Email"
      sx={{ mt: 2 }}
    ></TextField>
    <TextField
      inputRef={messageRef}
      type="text"
      id="form-msg"
      label="Message"
      multiline
      rows={5}
      sx={{ mt: 2 }}
    ></TextField>
  </Box>
```

This will give the correct output in the console log

Comment: This worked, I had no clue about this... thank you so much!

Comment: No Problem, Always check MUI docs as they work slightly different to most react standard components

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `inputRef` instead of `ref` for more information refer to the official doc. https://mui.com/api/text-field/

Comment: Thanks so much the link, ill take a look

Answer (score 0):

Use inputRef instead of ref for material UI text field component .
Reference :  https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#main-content